# The area region bounded by $y=3x$, $x=5$ and $x$-axis

Tags: integration, volume

Find the area region bounded by $y=3x$, $x=5$ and $x$-axis, hence find the volume revolved at $y$-axis $(360^\circ)$ and $y$-axis ($180^\circ$). How to find the volume and what it is mean by 'hence'. For the area i get the answer $75/2$ units. Please help since i cannot configure it other way around

Comment: What do you mean by $360$ and $180$?

Comment: 360 and 180 Degree.sorry i dont know how to make that sign

Comment: I'm still confused. There is only one y-axis. Are you asking the volume of the region you specified about the y-axis?

Comment: Yeah i copy the entire question.

Comment: Merely copying the "entire question" may not result in Readers giving your post thorough consideration.  It would greatly improve your Question if you added context, such as what you tried or what you failed to understand about tackling the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, plot the lines, $y=3x$, $x=5$ then one should find that  the region bounded by the lines $y=3x$, $x=5$ & x-axis is a right triangle having vertices at $(0, 0)$, $(5, 0)$ & $(5, 15)$ hence, its area is given as $$A=\int_{x=0}^{x=5} y\ dx$$  $$=\int_{x=0}^{x=5} (3x)\ dx=3\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^5=\color{red}{\frac{75}{2}}$$  Now, the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the curve (line) $y=3x$ about $y$-axis $$=\text{volume of complementary cylinder}-\text{volume of cone of rotation}$$
$$=\pi r^2l-\int_{y=0}^{y=15}\pi x^2\ dy $$
$$=\pi(5)^2(15)-\int_{y=0}^{y=15}\pi \left(\frac y3\right)^2\ dy $$

$$=375\pi-\frac{\pi}{9}\left[\frac{y^3}{3}\right]_{y=0}^{y=15} $$
$$=375\pi-125\pi=\color{red}{250\pi}$$

Comment: Why it is a cylinder?i think i visualize a cone

Comment: @Ameet: Try to visualize or draw a rough diagram. It will be a cone if the line $y=3x$ is rotated about the x-axis but the line $y=3x$ is rotated about the y-axis hence the solid will be cylinder-cone composite